# Python minor version updating with existing site packages

Tags: python, version

How can I update the Python minor version (3.11.6 to 3.12.0) with existing site packages?

Previously, I tried to update the Python minor version (3.9.x to 3.10.x,  3.10.x to 3.11.x), but it was installed as new software. A new folder will be created there, so a new site packages folder will also be created. Therefore, the previously installed modules have to be reinstalled to the new Python version.

This problem does not occur when the patch version is installed. Because there is an option to update the existing version to the next.

(In this case, I don't need to create [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).)

Comment: Would `pip freeze > requirements.txt`/`pip install -r requirements.txt` work for you?

Comment: what happen from this :"pip freeze > requirements.txt.". Is it backup my already ( lib > sight packages ) existing modules ?

Comment: In simple terms, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following steps:

1. You should do `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.
2. Install the newer Python version as the new software. You should uninstall your current Python before doing this.
3. After installing, do `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all your packages. (Make sure you're in the current directory as that file)

Hope that helps!

Comment: what happen from this :"pip freeze > requirements.txt.".      Is it backup my already ( lib > sight packages ) existing modules ?

Comment: There's no need to uninstall older versions. Having multiple Python interpreters on the same machine is fine and is even required to run, say, [`tox`](https://pypi.org/project/tox/).

Comment: @sonny this command will list down all the packages you've installed in your system and the ">" is used to put it in a text file

Comment: @InSync Personally it would be easier as you don't have to bother with conflicting paths.